# How to reload custom layout of nuxt .js?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

> admin.vue (A layout)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <adminAssets />
    <div v-if="getUserInfo._id">
      <adminHeader />
    </div>
    <nuxt />
    <div v-if="getUserInfo._id">
        <adminFooter />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name:'adminLayout',
    mounted() {
        this.getUserDetails();
    },
}
</script>
```

Here admin.vue failed to load other components using nuxt-link. How can i reload/refresh the default layout or vue components. ?

Comment: provide a full proper reproduction of problem. Your code and question doesnt make much sense.